# DevExpress MVC 17.1 How to open a Popup Window when the ValueChange event is called in a LargeDataComboBox

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I need that at the time the ValueChanged event of the [LargeDataComboBox](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDataEditorsDemos/Editors/LargeDataComboBox) is called (when I click on a row in the drop-down list) a Popup Window is displayed.

_searchPanel.cshtml

```
    @Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "comboBoxSearchPanel";
        settings.Height = 30;
        settings.SelectedIndex = 0;
        settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown;
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "SearchPanel", Action = "SearchPanel" };
        settings.Properties.CallbackPageSize = 30;
        settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains;
        settings.Properties.FilterMinLength = 2;
        settings.Properties.ClearButton.DisplayMode = ClearButtonDisplayMode.OnHover;
        settings.Properties.ValueField = "id_usuario";
        settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(string);
        settings.Properties.TextFormatString = "{0} {1}";
        settings.Properties.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "iduser";
            column.Caption = "User";
        });
        settings.Properties.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "fullname";
            column.Caption = "FUllName";
            column.Width = 175;
        });
        settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged = "function(s, e) { OnValueChangeSearchPanel(s, e)}";
    }
).BindList(Model).GetHtml()
```

function where the ValueChanged event is called

```
    function OnValueChangeSearchPanel(s, e) {
        var x = s.GetSelectedItem().text.split(" ");
        console.log(x[0]);
//I need to replace the alert with a popup
        alert(x[0]);
    }
```

_popupWindow.cshtml

```
@Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "popupUser";
    settings.AllowDragging = true;
    settings.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
    settings.CloseAction = CloseAction.CloseButton;
    settings.HeaderText = "User";
    settings.SetContent(() =>
    {
        ViewContext.Writer.Write(
          "<h1>" + "Welcome" + "</h1>"
        );
    });
```

Diagram of how it should work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code below does the trick

```
function OnValueChangeSearchPanel(s, e) {
        var x = s.GetSelectedItem().text.split(" ");
        popupUser.Show();
    }
```

Your Helper should look like this (complete code [here](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDockAndPopupsDemos/PopupControl/ClientSideAPI))

```
@Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "popupUser";
    settings.AllowDragging = true;
    settings.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
    settings.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
    settings.CloseAction = CloseAction.CloseButton;
    settings.PopupAction = PopupAction.None;
    settings.HeaderText = "User";
    settings.SetContent(() =>
    {
        ViewContext.Writer.Write(
          "<h1>" + "Welcome" + "</h1>"
        );
    });
```

Comment: when the OnValueChangeSearchPanel function is called, it displays the error: "popupContact.show is not a function"

Comment: I added **settings.EnableClientSideAPI = true**; but still showing the same error: _popupContact.show is not a function_

Comment: @bryannsi I think the popup name is _popupUser_?

Comment: yes, it right name. I have 3 files. 1- _searchPanel.cshtml (partial view where the other partial view should be called: **_ popupWindow.cshtml **) 2- The popup control: **popupWindow.cshtml** and 3- .js file, (the script that contains the method: **popup User.Show ()**)